# how to wrire a mysql query to solve this problem?

Tags: mysql

Given a table called "bugs" with the following columns (id, token, title, category, device, reported_at, created_at, updated_at). Find the title of the bug with token = "token660" and reported_at on "2020-08-30".
I tried
SELECT title FROM bugs WHERE token ='token660' AND reported_at='2020-08-30';"
and it 's very slow .
how to optimize it ?

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this?

Comment: Start with a basic SQL query tutorial for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: @MarkB thanks i tried "SELECT title FROM bugs WHERE token ='token660' AND reported_at='2020-08-30';" and it consumes much time i need to optimize it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i updated answer in the comment above

Comment: Please add your table definition the output of an explain and how many rows does the table have

Comment: @P.Salmon the statements doesn't imply this i need to optmize as i can

Comment: Just create a multi-column index on the two fields in the where clause.

Comment: @Shadow how to implement this in mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you are always searching for results using token and reported_at as the condition you could add an index on those columns:

```
CREATE INDEX bugs_idx ON bugs(token, reported_at);
```

This will create an index on those 2 columns and make all searches for those columns going much faster. You should read up on indexes, when you learn about indexes the database will start to work on a whole new level.

If you are sure that the columns token and reported_at are always unique in combination you could add a unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bugs_idx ON bugs(token, reported_at);
```

This will block inserts if they are not unique though.

When you added the index it will keep it self up to date and you can run your original query and it should start to run fast after creating the index.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution i 'm eager to learn inexing now but i want to ask another question ? should i run an ordinary select after indexing now ?

Comment: CREATE INDEX bugs_idx ON bugs(token, reported_at);SELECT title FROM bugs WHERE token ='token660' AND reported_at='2020-08-30';

Comment: The query "CREATE INDEX bugs_idx ON bugs(token, reported_at);" should only be executed one time. Never again. Now the index is created. Then you can run your SELECT as before. It should now be faster.

Comment: I can't run indexing here in the problem as it implies that i can only read the data ? anyway to optimize it without indexing @MrApnea

Comment: Ok. So you only have read access? Then I am afraid there is nothing more you can do. The query is simple enough that the database should have no problem doing a good search and the query can't be simplified much more. Indexing is the way to optimize slow queries, sometimes the query can be badly written and you can rewrite it but not in this case. Try to talk to someone who has write-access and see if they can add the index. Then your queries will still go fast, it doesn't matter who create the index, just that it is there.